# windows phone image overlay

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7

I want to know how to overlay one image over the over in Windows Phone. I did some search online, a lot of people suggest put two images into one grid and adjust the margin. However, my case is a little different. I'm making the background image of the secondary tile, I want to integrate the two images, store it locally and make the tile. So I can't put them into a grid. So what should I do in this case? Thanks!

Comment: I think that both images are generated locally

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create `UserControl` with any layout you wish (`173x173px`). Then, when you need to generate a tile, put this control to a page (probably out of the screen) and make and image from it with `new WriteableBitmap(YourTile, null);`. Than save these image to the `/Shared/ShellContent/` and you are done

Probably there are better solutions for this task but this works fine too

Answer (score 1):

I made this work using Ku6opr method using the following

```
WriteableBitmap bmp = new WriteableBitmap(173, 173);
bmp.Render(renderRoot, new TranslateTransform());
bmp.Invalidate();
```

where renderRoot is the usercontrol containing the Grid and the Image. I then save the bmp to the /Shared/ShellContent folder in Isolated storage.